# Is this video of a boxing kangaroo match authentic?

Tags: zoology, video

[Video link here](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=756699784340323)

It's awesome, weird, and unbelievable at the same time. If it was edited, I'm not sure how they did it. It LOOKS authentic but I would want confirmation.

Anyone who has more info on this video?

Comment: Videos of kangaroos boxing (which includes this one): https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kangaroo+boxing

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3ILA2mEjN8

Answer (score 14):

I can't prove that this video is **not** faked.

What I can do is show that boxing matches between humans and kangaroos are not at all extraordinary, and hence the evidence we require to accept that this video is genuine is relatively low, and we can provisionally accept it as probably genuine.

Boxing matches between humans and kangaroos used to be a fairly common side-show event.

The [Early Sports and Pop Culture History Blog](http://esnpc.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/australias-boxing-kangaroo-from.html) attributes the first occurrence to around 1891 in Philadelphia.

Soon, in New South Wales in Australia it became entertainment:

> Jack the Fighting Kangaroo has taken up his position as a public entertainer at the Waxworks, where he gives an exhibition of his warlike instincts every afternoon at three o’clock, and every evening at nine - his antagonist being Professor Lindermann – for whom the kangaroo entertains such a feeling of respect – or admiration – which ever it may be – that he never takes a mean advantage of his opponent – which says a good deal for the kangaroo.

[This page](http://www.southsearepublic.org/article/3/read/australian_vexillology/) makes an unreferenced claim that coincides with my understanding:

> In the late 1800's troupes would travel the country towns in outback Australia with boxing kangaroos. Local lads would pay to fight a kangaroo that had boxing gloves over its claws.

Here are some historical films that featured kangaroo boxing from [1895](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_Kangaroo_(film)) and [1896](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boxing_Kangaroo).

While rare, these events still happen. In [2013](http://www.kctv5.com/story/20960007/kangaroo-boxing-catches-attention-of-police) a bout caused controversy.

It is reasonable to believe that the video is not faked because its contents are not impossible or even unlikely.

Comment: Anecdotally, once I saw the 'roo have a couple of goes at the referee, I was fairly convinced this was a genuine video, if not a genuine fight.